# ExtJS - Complex form serialization

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a complex form which I can't use form serialization technique. There are many fields as well as dynamic grid ( the grid dynamically generating upon user choosing some criteria ) inside the form.

What I want to do, collect user inputs/selections + adding selected records that available in the grid then finally making a JSON array with those datas to be able to post server side.

My guess, I can use `getCmp` function of the ExtJS to take whole datas but as you might guess this way little bit hard to maintain. Also, I have no idea to get grid data with this way!

PS : Code is little bit long so that I cropped some parts.

**MODEL AND STORE DEFINITIONS**

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '<?php echo js_url(); ?>resources/ux');

Ext.require([
  'Ext.grid.*',
  'Ext.data.*',
  'Ext.form.*',
  'Ext.state.*',
  'Ext.util.*',
  'Ext.layout.container.Column',
  'Ext.selection.CheckboxModel',
  'Ext.ux.RowExpander',
  'Ext.ux.statusbar.StatusBar'  
]);

var navigate = function (panel, direction) {

    var layout = panel.getLayout();

    layout[direction]();

    Ext.getCmp('move-prev').setDisabled(!layout.getPrev());
    Ext.getCmp('move-next').setDisabled(!layout.getNext());
};

// Article Model
Ext.define('Article', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'ARTICLE_ID', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'DESCRIPTION', type: 'string'}
    ]
});

// Article Json Store
var articles = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    model: 'Article',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>create/get_articles',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'artList',
            idProperty: 'ARTICLE_ID'
        }
    }
});

winArticle = new Ext.Window({
width: 600,
modal: true,
title: 'Artikel Seçimi',
closeAction: 'hide',
bodyPadding: 10,
items: new Ext.Panel({
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Artikel Sorgulama',
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            layout: 'anchor',
            defaults: {
                anchor: '100%'
            },
            height: '76px',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    defaultType: 'textfield',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'combobox',
                            id: 'articleNo',
                            inputWidth: 320,
                            fieldLabel: 'ARTİKEL NO',
                            fieldStyle: 'height: 26px',
                            margin: '10 15 0 0',
                            triggerAction: 'query',
                            pageSize: true
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'SORGULA',
                            width: 100,
                            scale: 'medium',
                            margin: '8 0 0 0'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Artikel Bilgileri',
            height: '140px',
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    defaultType: 'textfield',
                    fieldDefaults: {
                        labelAlign: 'top'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            fieldLabel: 'ARTİKEL TANIMI',
                            name: 'artDesc',
                            flex: 3,
                            margins: '0 5 0 0'
                        },
                        {
                            fieldLabel: 'PAKET İÇERİĞİ',
                            name: 'artgebi',
                            flex: 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    defaultType: 'textfield',
                    id: 'artContainer1',
                    fieldDefaults: {
                        labelAlign: 'top'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            fieldLabel: 'SUBSYS',
                            name: 'artSubsys',
                            flex: 1,
                            margins: '0 5 0 0'
                        },
                        {
                            fieldLabel: 'VARIANT',
                            name: 'artVariant',
                            flex: 1,
                            margins: '0 5 0 0'
                        },
                        {
                            fieldLabel: 'VARIANT TANIMI',
                            name: 'artVariantDesc',
                            flex: 2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Aksiyon Seviyeleri',
            id: 'article-fieldset',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    id: 'btnArticleLevelAdd',
                    text: 'LEVEL EKLE',
                    scale: 'medium',
                    width: 100,
                    style: 'float: right',
                    margin: '0 7 0 0',
                    handler: function() {

                        var getLevels = function() {
                            var count = winArticle.down('fieldset[id=article-fieldset]').items.items.length;
                            return count;
                        }

                        var count = getLevels();

                        if (count === 3) {
                            Ext.getCmp('btnArticleLevelAdd').disable();
                        }

                        var container = 'artContainer' + count;
                        //console.log(container);

                        Ext.getCmp('article-fieldset').add([
                            {
                                xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                                layout: 'hbox',
                                id: 'artContainer' + count,
                                defaultType: 'textfield',
                                fieldDefaults: {
                                    labelAlign: 'top'
                                },
                                items: [
                                    {

                                        name: 'artLevel' + count,
                                        allowBlank: false,
                                        inputWidth: 216,
                                        fieldStyle: 'text-align: right; font-size: 13pt; background-color: #EAFFCC;',
                                        margins: '0 5 5 0'
                                    },
                                    {

                                        name: 'artValue' + count,
                                        allowBlank: false,
                                        inputWidth: 216,
                                        fieldStyle: 'text-align: right; font-size: 13pt; background-color: #EAFFCC;',
                                        margins: '0 5 0 0'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'button',
                                        text: 'SİL',
                                        width: 40,
                                        cls: 'btn-article-remove',
                                        handler: function() {
                                            if(count <= 3) {
                                                Ext.getCmp('btnArticleLevelAdd').enable();
                                            } else {
                                                Ext.getCmp('btnArticleLevelAdd').disable();
                                            }
                                            winArticle.down('fieldset[id=article-fieldset]').remove(container);
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]);
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    id: 'article-level-container',
                    defaultType: 'textfield',
                    fieldDefaults: {
                        labelAlign: 'top'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            fieldLabel: 'LEVEL',
                            name: 'artLevel',
                            inputWidth: 216,
                            margins: '0 5 5 0',
                            allowBlank: false,
                            fieldStyle: 'text-align: right; font-size: 13pt; background-color: #EAFFCC;'
                        },
                        {
                            fieldLabel: 'VALUE',
                            name: 'artValue',
                            inputWidth: 216,
                            allowBlank: false,
                            blankText: 'zorunlu alan, boş bırakılamaz',
                            fieldStyle: 'text-align: right; font-size: 13pt; background-color: #EAFFCC;',
                            listeners: {
                                change: function(textfield, newValue, oldValue) {
                                    if(oldValue == 'undefined' || newValue == '') {
                                        Ext.getCmp('btnArticleSave').disable();
                                    } else {
                                        Ext.getCmp('btnArticleSave').enable();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}),
buttons: [
    {
        text: 'KAPAT',
        scale: 'medium',
        width: 100,
        cls: 'btn-article-close',
        listeners: {
            click: function() {
                winArticle.close();
            }
        }
    },
    '->',
    {
        text: 'EKLE',
        scale: 'medium',
        disabled: true,
        width: 100,
        margin: '0 9 0 0',
        cls: 'btn-article-save',
        id: 'btnArticleSave'
    }
]
});
```

**EXT.ONREADY FUNCTION**

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

Ext.QuickTips.init();

Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider({
    expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7))
}));

var Discounts = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    id: 'discount-types',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    width: 760,
    height: 600,
    title: 'DNR TANIMLAMA / SCREEN 0',
    layout: 'card',
    bodyStyle: 'padding:20px',
    defaults: {
        border: false,
        anchor: '100%'
    },
    style: {
        'box-shadow': '0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)',
        '-webkit-box-shadow': '0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
    },
    frame: true,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'ÖNCEKİ ADIM',
            id: 'move-prev',
            cls: 'np-button',
            scale: 'medium',
            iconCls: 'dnr-prev-icon',
            iconAlign: 'left',
            handler: function (btn) {
                navigate(btn.up('panel'), 'prev');
                var itemd = Discounts.getLayout().getActiveItem();
                Discounts.setTitle('DNR TANIMLAMA ' + ' / ' + itemd.cardTitle);
                Ext.getCmp('dnr-submit').disable();
                Ext.getCmp('dnr-submit').setVisible(false);
            },
            disabled: true
        },
        {
            text: 'SONRAKİ ADIM',
            id: 'move-next',
            scale: 'medium',
            cls: 'np-button',
            iconCls: 'dnr-next-icon',
            iconAlign: 'right',
            handler: function (btn) {
                navigate(btn.up('panel'), 'next');
                var itemd = Discounts.getLayout().getActiveItem();
                Discounts.setTitle('DNR TANIMLAMA ' + ' / ' + itemd.cardTitle);
                var cardNum = Discounts.items.indexOf(itemd);

                if (cardNum == 3) {
                    Ext.getCmp('dnr-submit').enable();
                    Ext.getCmp('dnr-submit').setVisible(true);
                }
            },
            disabled: true
        },
        '->',
        {
            text: '&nbsp KAYDET ',
            id: 'dnr-submit',
            scale: 'medium',
            iconCls: 'dnr-submit-icon',
            iconAlign: 'right',
            cls: 'dnr-submit',
            disabled: true,
            hidden: true,
            handler: function (btn) {

            }
        }
    ],
    items: [
        {
            id: 'screen-0',
            cardTitle: 'SCREEN 0',
            layout: 'form',
            items: [
                {
                    layout: {
                        type: 'vbox',
                        align: 'center'
                    },
                    margin: '60 0 0 0',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'combobox',
                            inputWidth: 295,
                            fieldLabel: 'DNR TİPİ',
                            fieldStyle: 'height: 26px',
                            id: 'discount-type',
                            store: discounts,
                            valueField: 'DNR_TYPE_ID',
                            displayField: 'DNR_TYPE_DESC',
                            queryMode: 'remote',
                            forceSelection: true,
                            stateful: true,
                            stateId: 'cmb_disc_type',
                            allowBlank: false,
                            emptyText: 'DNR tipini seçiniz...',
                            triggerAction: 'all',
                            listeners: {
                                select: function (e) {
                                    var discType = Ext.getCmp('discount-type').getValue();
                                    var discDetail = Ext.getCmp('discount-detail');

                                    discdetails.removeAll();

                                    if (discType != 0) {
                                        discDetail.setDisabled(false);
                                        discdetails.proxy.extraParams = { 'dnrtype': discType };
                                        discdetails.load();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'combobox',
                            inputWidth: 400,
                            fieldStyle: 'height: 26px',
                            id: 'discount-detail',
                            valueField: 'ID',
                            displayField: 'DNR_TITLE',
                            store: discdetails,
                            forceSelection: true,
                            stateful: true,
                            stateId: 'cmb_disc_detail',
                            margin: '25 0 0 0',
                            disabled: true,
                            allowBlank: false,
                            msgTarget: 'side',
                            emptyText: 'İNDİRİM TİPİNİ SEÇİNİZ...',
                            blankText: 'İndirim tipi boş olamaz!',
                            triggerAction: 'all',
                            listeners: {
                                select: function (e) {
                                    var discDetail = Ext.getCmp('discount-detail').getValue();

                                    if (discDetail != 'null') {
                                        var value = discdetails.getAt(discdetails.find('ID', discDetail)).get('DNR_DESCRIPTION');
                                        Ext.getCmp('dnr-type-desc-panel').setVisible(true);
                                        Ext.getCmp('dnr-type-desc-panel').update(value);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textarea',
                            grow: false,
                            name: 'invoiceText',
                            fieldLabel: 'FATURA METNİ',
                            id: 'invoice-text',
                            blankText: 'Fatura metni boş olamaz!',
                            width: 400,
                            height: 60,
                            margin: '30 0 0 0',
                            allowBlank: false,
                            msgTarget: 'side',
                            listeners: {
                                change: function (e) {
                                    if (Ext.getCmp('invoice-text').getValue().length === 0) {
                                        Ext.getCmp('move-next').disable();
                                    } else {
                                        Ext.getCmp('move-next').enable();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            id: 'dnr-type-desc-panel',
                            layout: {type: 'hbox', align: 'stretch'},
                            height: 145,
                            width: 400,
                            cls: 'dnr-desc-panel',
                            margin: '60 0 0 0',
                            html: '&nbsp',
                            hidden: true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 'screen-1',
            cardTitle: 'SCREEN 1',
            layout: 'form',
            items: [
                {
                    layout: 'column',
                    width: 730,
                    height: 90,
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'fieldset',
                            title: 'ARTİKEL / HEDEF GRUP / MAL GRUBU SEÇİMİ',
                            cls: 'dnr-fieldset',
                            width: 730,
                            height: 80,
                            margin: '0',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'buttongroup',
                                    columns: 5,
                                    columnWidth: 140,
                                    frame: false,
                                    margin: '5 0 0 18',
                                    items: [
                                        {
                                            text: 'ARTİKEL',
                                            scale: 'medium',
                                            margin: '0 18px 0 0',
                                            width: 120,
                                            height: 36,
                                            id: 'btn-article',
                                            cls: 'btn-grp-choose btn-grp-article',
                                            listeners: {
                                                click: function () {
                                                    winArticle.center();
                                                    winArticle.show();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: 'PUAR',
                                            scale: 'medium',
                                            margin: '0 18px 0 0',
                                            width: 120,
                                            height: 36,
                                            cls: 'btn-grp-choose btn-grp-puar',
                                            listeners: {
                                                click: function() {
                                                    winPuar.show();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: 'MAL GRUBU',
                                            scale: 'medium',
                                            margin: '0 18px 0 0',
                                            width: 120,
                                            height: 36,
                                            cls: 'btn-grp-choose btn-grp-choose',
                                            listeners: {
                                                click: function() {
                                                    winArticleGroup.show();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: 'HEDEF GRUP',
                                            scale: 'medium',
                                            margin: '0 18px 0 0',
                                            width: 120,
                                            height: 36,
                                            cls: 'btn-grp-choose btn-grp-target',
                                            listeners: {
                                                click: function() {
                                                    winTargetGroup.show();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: 'SUPPLIER',
                                            scale: 'medium',
                                            width: 120,
                                            height: 36,
                                            cls: 'btn-grp-choose btn-grp-supplier',
                                            listeners: {
                                                click: function() {
                                                    winSupplier.show();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                    id: 'article-grid',
                    selType: 'rowmodel',
                    elStatus: true,
                    plugins: [
                        { ptype: 'cellediting', clicksToEdit: 1},
                        { ptype: 'datadrop'}
                    ],
                    /* ***************************************************************
                     * here is the tricky part! when user change any fields above
                     * this grid will dynamically generate upon user request. So that
                     * we arent sure which columns will be available.
                     * ***************************************************************/
                    columns: [
                        {
                            text: 'COLUMN A',
                            dataIndex: ''
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        renderTo: 'content'
})
});
```

Comment: What I suggested will read any data from the records within the store, no matter of what type they are.

Comment: Dear @sra I am curious that how can we handle selected grid records? Realy didn't solve in last three days. When user specify a criteria, I can create grid store on the fly then showing the grid panel. I can't do it last part which is making a JsonStore with whole data. There should be easy way to do that. It doesn't matter what data available in the JsonStore which I can handle in the server side.

Comment: I am not sure if I really understand what your goal is... Do you want to 1. get only selected records from the grids, 2. get only modified records from the grids, 3. get all records or 4. something totally different. What datastructure do you expect? I mean you will still need to be able to cast the data back to objects in the backend...?

Comment: Dear @sra, get only selected records from the grid with all other form fields. As you can see from the source code, there are three panel. When user start from the first panel, he/she choosing necessary fields. When user reach the last panel, I would like to get all records that he/she selected beginning of the process which is including grid.

Comment: Ok, please see my edit and give me feedback

Comment: @sra, one more question. What if just want to get all records that loaded in the grid instead of selection model?

Comment: You can get anything that is available/accessable by the grid. So to get call `form.down('grid').getStore().data.items` See my edit under the last for some more options

Comment: And not to forget; you're welcome ;) glad to help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated answer**

After some clarification I think the answer should be quite easy (at least I think so) For the following answer I assume that you are inside the form at the time you want to fetch the form & grid data and that there is only one `Ext.form.Panel`:

```
// Navigate up to the form:
var form = this.up('form'),
// get the form values
    data = form.getValues(),
// get the selected record from the grid
    gridRecords = form.down('grid').getSelectionModel().getSelected(),
// some helper variables
    len = gridRecords.length,
    recordData = [];

// normalize the model data by copying just the data objects into the array
for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
    recordData .push(gridRecords[i].data);
}
// apply the selected grid records to the formdata. For that you will need a property name, I will use just 'gridRecords' but you may change it
data.gridRecords = recordData;

// send all back via a ajax request
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'demo/sample',
    success: function(response, opts) {
        // your handler
    },
    failure: function(response, opts) {
        // your handler
    },
    jsonData: data
});
```

That should it be

To provide some more options of data that can be fetched from/by the grid

```
// get all data that is currently in the store
form.down('grid').getStore().data.items
// get all new and updated records
form.down('grid').getStore().getModifiedRecords()
// get all new records
form.down('grid').getStore().getNewRecords()
// get all updated records
form.down('grid').getStore().getUpdatedRecords()
```

**Old answer (for more complex scenarios) below**

> What you told:
>
> You have a grid with forms and maybe grids. Where you need to also
>   readout the grids when fetching the data from the form.
>
> In the answer below I will just cover **getValues**, **binding/unbinding events** to each grid and not
>
> - form load/submit
> - record load/update
> - setting values

**My recommendation is to make your form much more intelligent so that it is capable of handling this.**

*What do I mean by?*

A default form cares about all fields that are inserted anywhere in it's body. In 99,9% this is perfectly fine but not for all. Your form also need to take care about grids that get inserted.

*How it can be done*

First thing is that when you make your Grids parts of a form I recommend to give them a name property. Second is that you need to know how a form gather and utilizes the fields so that you be able to copy that for grids. For that you need to take a look at the [Ext.form.Basic](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic) class [constructor](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Basic.html#Ext-form-Basic-constructor) where the important part is this

```
// We use the monitor here as opposed to event bubbling. The problem with bubbling is it doesn't
// let us react to items being added/remove at different places in the hierarchy which may have an
// impact on the dirty/valid state.
me.monitor = new Ext.container.Monitor({
    selector: '[isFormField]',
    scope: me,
    addHandler: me.onFieldAdd,
    removeHandler: me.onFieldRemove
});
me.monitor.bind(owner);
```

What happens here is that a monitor get initialized that from this on will look for any field that get inserted into the bound componenent where the monitor will call the appropriate handler. Currently the monitor is looking for fields but you will need one that is looking for grids. Such a monitor would look like:

```
me.gridMonitor = new Ext.container.Monitor({
    selector: 'grid',
    scope: me,
    addHandler: me.onGridAdd,
    removeHandler: me.onGridRemove
});
me.gridMonitor.bind(owner);
```

Because I don't know much about your datastructure I cannot tell you which gridevents you might need but you should register/unregister them in the addHandler/removeHandler like

```
onGridAdd: function(grid) {
    var me = this;
    me.mon(grid,'select',me.yourHandler,me);
},
onGridRemove: function(grid) {
    var me = this;
    me.mun(grid,'select',me.yourHandler,me);
}
```

In addition you will need the following helper methods

```
/**
 * Return all the {@link Ext.grid.Panel} components in the owner container.
 * @return {Ext.util.MixedCollection} Collection of the Grid objects
 */
getGrids: function() {
    return this.gridMonitor.getItems();
},

/**
 * Find a specific {@link Ext.grid.Panel} in this form by id or name.
 * @param {String} id The value to search for (specify either a {@link Ext.Component#id id} or
 * {@link Ext.grid.Panel name }).
 * @return {Ext.grid.Panel} The first matching grid, or `null` if none was found.
 */
findGrid: function(id) {
    return this.getGrids().findBy(function(f) {
        return f.id === id || f.name === id;
    });
},
```

And most important the method that get's the data from the grids. Here we need to override

```
getValues: function(asString, dirtyOnly, includeEmptyText, useDataValues) {
    var values  = {},
        fields  = this.getFields().items,
        grids  = this.getGrids().items, // the grids found by the monitor
        f,
        fLen    = fields.length,
        gLen    = grids.length, // gridcount
        isArray = Ext.isArray,
        grid, gridData, gridStore, // some vars used while reading the grid content
        field, data, val, bucket, name;

    for (f = 0; f < fLen; f++) {
        field = fields[f];

        if (!dirtyOnly || field.isDirty()) {
            data = field[useDataValues ? 'getModelData' : 'getSubmitData'](includeEmptyText);

            if (Ext.isObject(data)) {
                for (name in data) {
                    if (data.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                        val = data[name];

                        if (includeEmptyText && val === '') {
                            val = field.emptyText || '';
                        }

                        if (values.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                            bucket = values[name];

                            if (!isArray(bucket)) {
                                bucket = values[name] = [bucket];
                            }

                            if (isArray(val)) {
                                values[name] = bucket.concat(val);
                            } else {
                                bucket.push(val);
                            }
                        } else {
                            values[name] = val;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // begin new part
    for (g = 0; g < gLen; g++) {
        grid = grids[f];
        gridStore = grid.getStore();
        gridData = [];

        // You will need a identification variable to determine which data should be taken from the grid. Currently this demo implement three options
        // 0 only selected
        // 1 complete data within the store
        // 2 only modified records (this can be splitted to new and updated)
        var ditems = grid.submitData === 0 ? grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection() : 
                     grid.submitData === 1 ? gridStore.getStore().data.items : gridStore.getStore().getModifiedRecords(),
            dlen = ditems.length;
        for(d = 0; d < dLen; d++) {
            // push the model data to the current data list. It doesn't matter of which type the models (records) are, this will simply read the whole known data. Alternatively you may access the rawdata property if the reader does not know all fields.
            gridData.push(ditems[d].data);
        }
        // assign the array of record data to the grid-name property
        data[grid.name] = gridData;
    }
    // end new part
    if (asString) {
        values = Ext.Object.toQueryString(values);
    }
    return values;
}
```

Clued together should it look something like

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.Basic', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Basic',

    /**
     * Creates new form.
     * @param {Ext.container.Container} owner The component that is the container for the form, usually a {@link Ext.form.Panel}
     * @param {Object} config Configuration options. These are normally specified in the config to the
     * {@link Ext.form.Panel} constructor, which passes them along to the BasicForm automatically.
     */
    constructor: function(owner, config) {
        var me = this;

        me.callParent(arguments);
        // We use the monitor here as opposed to event bubbling. The problem with bubbling is it doesn't
        // let us react to items being added/remove at different places in the hierarchy which may have an
        // impact on the dirty/valid state.
        me.gridMonitor = new Ext.container.Monitor({
            selector: 'grid',
            scope: me,
            addHandler: me.onGridAdd,
            removeHandler: me.onGridRemove
        });
        me.gridMonitor.bind(owner);
    },

    onGridAdd: function(grid) {
        var me = this;
        me.mon(grid,'select',me.yourHandler,me);
    },

    onGridRemove: function(grid) {
        var me = this;
        me.mun(grid,'select',me.yourHandler,me);
    },

    /**
     * Return all the {@link Ext.grid.Panel} components in the owner container.
     * @return {Ext.util.MixedCollection} Collection of the Grid objects
     */
    getGrids: function() {
        return this.gridMonitor.getItems();
    },

    /**
     * Find a specific {@link Ext.grid.Panel} in this form by id or name.
     * @param {String} id The value to search for (specify either a {@link Ext.Component#id id} or
     * {@link Ext.grid.Panel name }).
     * @return {Ext.grid.Panel} The first matching grid, or `null` if none was found.
     */
    findGrid: function(id) {
        return this.getGrids().findBy(function(f) {
            return f.id === id || f.name === id;
        });
    },

    getValues: function(asString, dirtyOnly, includeEmptyText, useDataValues) {
        var values  = {},
            fields  = this.getFields().items,
            grids  = this.getGrids().items, // the grids found by the monitor
            f,
            fLen    = fields.length,
            gLen    = grids.length, // gridcount
            isArray = Ext.isArray,
            grid, gridData, gridStore, // some vars used while reading the grid content
            field, data, val, bucket, name;

        for (f = 0; f < fLen; f++) {
            field = fields[f];

            if (!dirtyOnly || field.isDirty()) {
                data = field[useDataValues ? 'getModelData' : 'getSubmitData'](includeEmptyText);

                if (Ext.isObject(data)) {
                    for (name in data) {
                        if (data.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                            val = data[name];

                            if (includeEmptyText && val === '') {
                                val = field.emptyText || '';
                            }

                            if (values.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                                bucket = values[name];

                                if (!isArray(bucket)) {
                                    bucket = values[name] = [bucket];
                                }

                                if (isArray(val)) {
                                    values[name] = bucket.concat(val);
                                } else {
                                    bucket.push(val);
                                }
                            } else {
                                values[name] = val;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // begin new part
        for (g = 0; g < gLen; g++) {
            grid = grids[f];
            gridStore = grid.getStore();
            gridData = [];

            // You will need a identification variable to determine which data should be taken from the grid. Currently this demo implement three options
            // 0 only selected
            // 1 complete data within the store
            // 2 only modified records (this can be splitted to new and updated)
            var ditems = grid.submitData === 0 ? grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection() : 
                         grid.submitData === 1 ? gridStore.getStore().data.items : gridStore.getStore().getModifiedRecords(),
                dlen = ditems.length;
            for(d = 0; d < dLen; d++) {
                // push the model data to the current data list. It doesn't matter of which type the models (records) are, this will simply read the whole known data. Alternatively you may access the rawdata property if the reader does not know all fields.
                gridData.push(ditems[d].data);
            }
            // add the store data as array to the grid-name property
            data[grid.name] = gridData;
        }
        // end new part
        if (asString) {
            values = Ext.Object.toQueryString(values);
        }
        return values;
    }
});
```

Next is to modify the form to use this basic form type

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.Panel', {
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    requires: ['Ext.ux.form.Basic'],

    /**
     * @private
     */
    createForm: function() {
        var cfg = {},
            props = this.basicFormConfigs,
            len = props.length,
            i = 0,
            prop;

        for (; i < len; ++i) {
            prop = props[i];
            cfg[prop] = this[prop];
        }
        return new Ext.ux.form.Basic(this, cfg);
    }
});
```

> **Note:**
>
> This is all untested! I've done something similar for various
>   customers to extend the capabilities of forms and I can tell tell that
>   this way will work very well and fast. At least it should show how it can be done and it can easily be tweaked to also set forms and/or load/update records.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this myself, but there is a thread that tries to deal with associated models via hasMany relationship. The problem is that everyone has slightly different expectations of what should happen during write operation of records. Serever side ORMs deal with this issue in somewhat difficult to understand manner and is often a sore spot for new developers.

Here is the forum thread that details a custom JSON writer to persist a parent record with it's children records.

Here is the code that seems to work at least for some folks:

```
Ext.data.writer.Json.override({
/*
 * This function overrides the default implementation of json writer. Any hasMany relationships will be submitted
 * as nested objects. When preparing the data, only children which have been newly created, modified or marked for
 * deletion will be added. To do this, a depth first bottom -> up recursive technique was used.
 */
getRecordData: function(record) {
    //Setup variables
    var me = this, i, association, childStore, data = record.data;

    //Iterate over all the hasMany associations
    for (i = 0; i < record.associations.length; i++) {
        association = record.associations.get(i);
        data[association.name] = null;
        childStore = record[association.storeName];

        //Iterate over all the children in the current association
        childStore.each(function(childRecord) {

            if (!data[association.name]){
                data[association.name] = [];
            }

            //Recursively get the record data for children (depth first)
            var childData = this.getRecordData.call(this, childRecord);

            /*
             * If the child was marked dirty or phantom it must be added. If there was data returned that was neither
             * dirty or phantom, this means that the depth first recursion has detected that it has a child which is
             * either dirty or phantom. For this child to be put into the prepared data, it's parents must be in place whether
             * they were modified or not.
             */
            if (childRecord.dirty | childRecord.phantom | (childData != null)){
                data[association.name].push(childData);
                record.setDirty();
            }
        }, me);

        /*
         * Iterate over all the removed records and add them to the preparedData. Set a flag on them to show that
         * they are to be deleted
         */
        Ext.each(childStore.removed, function(removedChildRecord) {
            //Set a flag here to identify removed records
            removedChildRecord.set('forDeletion', true);
            var removedChildData = this.getRecordData.call(this, removedChildRecord);
            data[association.name].push(removedChildData);
            record.setDirty();
        }, me);
    }

    //Only return data if it was dirty, new or marked for deletion.
    if (record.dirty | record.phantom | record.get('forDeletion')){
        return data;
    }
}
});
```

The full thread is located here:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?141957-Saving-objects-that-are-linked-hasMany-relation-with-a-single-Store/page5